# "to keep something as a memory" or "to keep something as a memento"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between 
 "to keep something as a [memory](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/memory)"
and "to keep something as a [memento](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/memento)"

First of all, although I think I heard of that usage of the word memory in this meaning, when I looked up a few online dictionaries, I could not see any example sentence given such " as a memory". Therefore, I am not sure if this usage is grammatically correct or idiomatic.

Secondly, does the word memento sound a bit too formal than the word memory for this following example sentence:

> I would like to keep the cup given as a gift as a memento of my trip to your country.

Answer (score 1):

'Memento' is not too formal; it is the normal word used for a physical object kept as a reminder of a trip, an event, a person, etc. As you have guessed, a memory is an intangible thing that exists in a person's head.